# accumulation point of the set $(-1,0]$.

Tags: general-topology

a) is $0$ accumulation point of the set $(-1,0]$ in the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$ ?

b) is $0$ accumulation point of the set $(-1,0]$ in the topology of the line $\mathbb R$ ?

My try:

a) No, {0} is open set in the discrete topology on $\mathbb R$ but

$(-1,0] ⋂ (${$0$}$-${$0$}$) =\phi$

and for (b)

yes, because

$∀ 0<\epsilon<1,{-\epsilon\over 2}∈((-\epsilon,\epsilon )-${$0$}$)⋂A≠ \phi$

for example, $\epsilon={1\over 2}$

${-1 \over 4}∈(({-1 \over 2},{1 \over 2}),-${$0$}$)⋂A≠∅$

but is true answer or not?

Comment: $\{0\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in the discrete topology. What points of $(-1, 0]$ does it intersect ?

Comment: I don't speak English well, but I think I understand what you mean and i edited my answer, what about now it's true or still wrong?, Thank you

Comment: Now it's much improved.  It's about open neighborhoods of 0

Comment: Thanks, but since now we don't take "neighborhoods" in course, we well take it soon :), my teacher say take any open set G contain 0, then show $(G-0) \cap A=\phi$.

Comment: An open set containing 0 is called an open neighbourhood of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slightly expanded based on the comments: in the usual topology, take any open set $O$ containing $0$. Then there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ (wlog $\varepsilon < 1$) such that $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \subseteq O$. By your remark $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\setminus \{0\} \cap A \neq \emptyset$, as indeed witnessed by $-\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \in A$. So $O \setminus \{0\}) \cap A \neq\emptyset $ as well. So $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

In the discrete topology we take $O = \{0\}$, which is open. But then $O \setminus \{0\} = \emptyset$, and so does not intersect $A$. This one example suffices to show that $0$ is *not* an accumulation point of $A$.

Comment: Thank You so so much, I am grateful.

Comment: Sorry, What are you mean by (wlog $\epsilon <1$)? I don't know the meaning of "wlog".

Comment: @Dima without loss of generality.  We can always take a smaller $\varepsilon$ if one $> 1$ works. It ensures that half of epsilon is in the interval.

Comment: yeah you are right, Thanks.